# how to wrap text in a data frame to print using grid.draw?

Tags: r, gridextra

[image]

I have a `data.frame` in which a column has multiple lines of text. How can I wrap the text to print the data frame using grid.draw ? I tried using strwrap but no luck.

```
A=data.frame(name=c("ABC","XYZ","DEF"),description=c(rep("This is an example for text wrap using grid.draw in package gridExtra",3))
```

Comment: Appreciate if you can add some data that we can work with.

Comment: Sorry about that. Adding it right away.

Comment: Hope the example helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use package `gridExtra` which has a function `grid.table`, and add `\n` into your data frame where you want the breaks:

```
A=data.frame(name=c("ABC","XYZ","DEF"),description=c(rep("This is an example for text wrap \nusing grid.draw in package gridExtra",3))
grid.newpage()
grid.table(A)
```

You can tune up the table pretty nicely using the various arguments.